# Difference between "!= true" and "== false"?

Tags: logic, operators, logical-operators

Are there any technical/logical differences between the comparison "!= true" and "== false" in programming languages, and if there are, which comparison should be chosen on what occasion?

Comment: Same thing. Usually `exp == false` is better expressed as `!exp`.

Comment: No, @aioobe, it's not.

Comment: @StingyJack I can guarantee you that if you search the source code on, say, github you'll find that `!exp` is more common than `exp == false`.

Comment: @aioobe - "better expressed" is not about what is most common. If your team members or code maintainers have good eyesight but not great, use bifocal lenses, or have general eyesight issues (all of these things seem to start at age 40 =/ ), there is less chance of a misread and resulting bug by using `if (IsReady() == false)` then by using `if (!IsReady())`. Then again the same is true if your audience has good eyesight, except they will constantly complain about the lack of `!` until a few years pass and then come to appreciate `== false`.

Comment: First of all, I never said that it's _always_ better. I said _usually_, and if `!exp` is the more prevalent form, it shows that the majority would agree with me on that. Secondly, I don't understand your argument about programmers with poor eyesight. Surely that scenario can't be the _usual_ scenario? This is the first time I've heard someone argue that you should format your code with programmers with poor eyesight in mind, and I've been programming for 23 years.

Comment: @aioobe - I had always used the negation operator until I worked on a team with an average age of probably 45 or older. Every month or two there would be a bug because of a missed negation operator. Once we changed to using `== false` this problem went away.  Also, personally I think/say "Is something false". The phrasing of "is not something" doesnt feel natural as a native en-US speaker.

Answer (score 11):

Logically there can be differences depending on the type of value that you are comparing and language you are using.  For example:

`x == false` implies `x != true`, but `x != true` does not always imply `x == false` because x can also be some nonsense value.

`1 + 1 = 3` is both `== false` and `!= true`.

`7 > cat` is neither `== false` and `!= true` since it is nonsense.

`x = null` is `!= true` but is not `== false`.

Comment: I think your `7 > cat` example is strange. It seems just as strange as the expression `cat == false` or `cat != true`, neither of which would compiler nor execute in any language I know of. Discussing the semantics of something that isn't a valid program seems strange to me.

Comment: @aioobe I would agree for the most part but I could see this happening in a weakly typed languages.  That is why I specified in my answer "depending on the type of value that you are comparing".

Comment: Another example might be a language (or formal structure) in which the type Boolean allows null values. In that case, a null might be neither true nor false and so !true might not be false.

Comment: @MattClarke thank you, I had that in my initial answer but edited it out after someone mentioned that it isn't accurate in Java.  You are correct in mentioning that it is still possible in some languages (or formal structure).  And since this question has no language tagged I will keep it in my answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: @EricG In such weakly typed languages, it can certainly be `true` or `false`. E.g. Erlang.

Answer (score 2):

Use accordingly what your code block is expecting.

e.g.

- if your code block is expecting `true` then use `if( true == fun() ) { // your code }`.
- if your code block is expecting any value except `false` then use `if( false != fun() ) { 
  // your code }`.