# Which one is safer to use? " ==TRUE" or " != FALSE"

Tags: c, boolean

Is it better to compare a boolean type variable with:

1. `== FALSE` and `!= FALSE`; or
2. `== TRUE` and `!= TRUE`?

Comment: If you have a Boolean variable `b`, my opinion is that `if(b)` and `if(!b)` are preferable.  If you must use explicit comparisons, `if(b != FALSE)` and `if(b == FALSE)` are preferable.  Explicit comparisons against `TRUE` can be quite dangerous, due to the possibility that `b` is neither 0 nor 1.  See also [question 9.2](http://c-faq.com/bool/bool2.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: it is safer to use `true` and `false` from `stdbool.h`

Comment: **Please, just don't!** Use `x = FALSE; if (x) {...}`  or `if (!x) {`.

Comment: Why would you even use a comparison? A comparison returns a boolean (as an `int`) Or did you define `FALSE` as `-1` and `TRUE` as `42`?

Comment: Unless `TRUE` has been defined to be something other than 1 and `FALSE` something other than 0, it's better not to do an explicit comparison at all.  Just use `if (b)` and `if (!b)`.

Comment: Neither is necessary, but "== TRUE" is wrong and dangerous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "!= true" and "== false"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682691/difference-between-true-and-false)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it better to compare a boolean type variable with " == FALSE" and " != FALSE" or with " ==FALSE" and " ==TRUE" ?

1. Neither.

With the C boolean type `_Bool`, do not use `==` or `!=` to assess truth-ness against a constant.
[@Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014718/which-one-is-safer-to-use-true-or-false/53015332#comment92933077_53014718) [@Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014718/which-one-is-safer-to-use-true-or-false/53015332#comment92933259_53014718) [@John Bode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014718/which-one-is-safer-to-use-true-or-false/53015332#comment92933514_53014718)

```
_Bool x;
if (x)   // to assess truth-ness
if (!x)   // to assess false-ness
```

2. If a strong desire remains to use `==`, `!=`, like many style issues, best to follow your group's coding guidelines.
3. Lacking group's coding guidelines - make them.

---

Use `<stdbool.h>` as able to access `bool, true, false` rather than code `TRUE`, `FALSE`.
[@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014718/which-one-is-safer-to-use-true-or-false/53015332#comment92933094_53014718)

---

> Which one is safer to use? “ ==TRUE” or “ != FALSE”

Note that comparing `a == TRUE` can fail unexpectedly as the operands are compared as integers, FP or pointers, not as boolean.  This may fail to compare truth-ness should `a` be a non-boolean with a "truth" value other than 1 even if `TRUE` is a boolean 1.

```
double a = 0.999999;
// Both are false
if (a == TRUE) { ... }   // The arithmetic value of `a` is used, not its "truth"
if (a == FALSE) { ... }
// better as 
if (a) { ... }   // As if `a != 0`
else { ... }
```

Consider cases where the "truth" is returned as non-zero, perhaps not 1.

```
if(islower('a') == TRUTH) ...  // The if() block might or might not execute
if(islower('a'))  ...          // The if() block will execute
```

`a != 0` or `a != false` tends to be safer.

---

Style: I find `==` code easier to follow than `!=` as negations add mental complexity for people. [Example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310592/meaning-and-interpretation-of-bilbos-half-as-well-quote)

Comment: A more relevant source to cite, than various other SO users, would be MISRA-C, which enforces logical/relational/equality operators to be treated as boolean functions. Just as in C++.

Answer (score 1):

- `TRUE` and `FALSE` is not standard C and should therefore not be used, unless perhaps you are coding against an old C90 library that uses them (such as Windows API).
- The boolean type in C is `_Bool`. It can be used as `bool` and should be set to values `true` or `false` from `stdbool.h`
- The need to explicitly compare a boolean against true/false suggests poor variable naming. A somewhat common naming standard for booleans is to prefix them with `is`, such as: `while(!isReady) { ... }`.
- The `==`and `!=` operators are equally safe. Both could in theory be mixed up with `=` and `=!`, but any decent compiler will warn for that ("assignment in expression"/"possible incorrect assignment").

Answer (score -2):

Everey syntax has its own meaning and there is not better or safer way. But you should always consider these special points in comparison to decide which syntax is safer in your case:

1. in C language NUMBERS represent booleans: 0 is **FALSE** and other numbers are **TRUE**. You may restrict to `stdbool.h` to prevent mixing up integers and boolean.
2. if you connect to SQL databse uisng **C** , in SQL, a comparison against **NULL** is not **true** nor **false**.
3. If are working in team I suggest to all team members to use `if (something==TRUE)` rather than `if(something)` because indicates that you mean boolean from `something` not an Integer. Meke sure that your temameates agree with this syntax and also make sure that you have considered case number 1!

Comment: "and other positive numbers are TRUE." is incomplete.  All numbers other than +/- 0 are true including ones greater than 0, less than 0, and even [not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).